# Minor Lefschetz principle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, model-theory, fields, mathematical-philosophy

I once read (I think) the following equivalent formulation of the Minor Lefschetz principle:

- If an elementary sentence holds for one algebraically closed field,
  then it holds for *every* algebraically closed field.

So without restrictions on the characteristic.

Is this version correct, is it really equivalent ? (I can not find any source anymore.)

Comment: If "elementary" means first order, this is false: $\forall x,2x=0$ holds for $\overline{\Bbb{F}}_2$, but not for $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5):

The correct statement is that the following are equivalent, for a sentence $\varphi$ in the first-order language of fields.

1. $\varphi$ is true in some algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.
2. $\varphi$ is true in every algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.
3. There exist arbitrarily large $p$ such that $\varphi$ is true in some algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$.
4. For all sufficiently large $p$, $\varphi$ is true in every algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$.

The proof is almost immediate from compactness and the completeness of the theories of algebraically closed fields of fixed characteristic (which is itself an easy consequence of quantifier-elimination).